# react button doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am a beginner in React, and I am trying to put a button on my page, but the button doesn't show up.
The following is my code(updated version after adding the div tag with a id "root" inside the body tag)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Gambling Online</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

</body>

<script  type="text/babel">
    console.log("dha");

    class Start extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <button className="start">
                    testing
                </button>
            );
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
  <Start />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


</script>
```

Comment: You need a <div> with id="root" in the body of your document.

Comment: I just try it, it still doesn't show up

Comment: where is the `< /head>` what about `<body>`  ? Do you see any error in console ?

Comment: It's hard to say. If this is your complete page here, it is not well-formed. You need to close <head> for one.

Comment: You have to put the script after the root div. Take a look at your browser console, there's probably an error about the element with ID root not being found

Comment: is that your index.html file? If so do you have a root element to render the button?

Comment: nothing in the console, but I saw this in the react tab(I am using the developer tool of react), "waiting for root to load"

Comment: I have added a <div id="root"></div> in my body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a babel transpiler in order to use `text/babel` script, add this in your `<head>` :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```